# Mongoose Map type incompatible with TypeScript type

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have the following interface for model schema:

```
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export interface ILog {
  tags: { [key: string]: string }[];
}

export interface ILogDocument extends ILog, Document {}
```

And there is the schema:

```
const logSchema = new Schema<ILogDocument>({
  tags: { type: Map, of: String },
});
```

So i get the following type error on my schema:

```
TS2322: Type '{ type: MapConstructor; of: StringConstructor; }' is not assignable to type 'SchemaDefinitionProperty<{ [key: string]: string; }[]> | undefined'.
```

I want to use proper type defintion, I tried `type: Schema.Types.Mixed` and its works, but is there a better way to specify mongoose type for `tags: { [key: string]: string }[]` ?

Answer (score 1):

`{ [key: string]: string }[]` is not exactly `Map`. You can use the Map type from TS.

```
import { Document, Schema } from 'mongoose';

export interface ILog {
  tags: Map<string, string>;
}

export interface ILogDocument extends ILog, Document {}

const logSchema = new Schema<ILogDocument>({
  tags: { type: Map, of: String }
});
```